# Apache change script without restart

Tags: python, apache

I wrote a simple Flask application on a VPS server in Apache

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

import sys
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "123"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

When I change the string `return "123"` to `return "123456"` and save it, it doesn't change when refreshing the site with Ctrl+F5.
It changes only when I restart the Apache server.
How can I change the file without a restart?

Answer (score 0):

You can try reloading. Even that will impact the incoming traffic though.If there are more than one servers you can do a rolling reload or restart.

If not you can do a graceful restart of apache where traffic wont be impacted, using

`apachectl -k graceful`

You can do without a restart or reload as well.

The reason why you are getting older code is,

1. you might have a compiled python code(bytecode) file which will be served for every new request, if your script is myscript.py, check if there is a myscript.pyc, which is a bytecode containing the older version of the script. You need to remove that.
2. If you are using wsgi module for serving python in apache, you need to look at the following link on how to reload source code.

   https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/ReloadingSourceCode.wiki

Comment: what reloading?im want next:if im change script file, and save it,and reload page change not accept

Comment: You can do without reload also, please check above.